# Image is viewable in browser, but still reported as 404

Tags: php

I have a test PHP script returning only PNG images to the client browser.

When opening my test route in the browser (e.g. https://mywebsite.com/testimage), the image is successfully displayed, however in console (and network) there's a 404 error reported!

How is this possible?

Also, this issue only occurs when deploying to my remote servers. On my localhost, there is no issue.

Immediately I think there needs to be additional headers or perhaps I'm missing an image data preparation step? As well, is it possible browser CORS pre-flight check is involved somehow?

Tested browsers, MacOS: Firefox, Chrome, Safari... fresh incognito windows.

To re-iterate, I can see the entire image in the browser tab, even though the PNG is marked as a 404 error in the browser console (and network). No other network entries exist (I'm viewing "All" network entries).

**Error code in Chrome:**

FYI No favicon activity seen anywhere (console or network tab), just one entry for the PNG response from server, with following details:

```
Request URL: https://mywebsite.com/testimage
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 
Remote Address: ***.***.***.***
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
content-type: image/png
date: Tue, 23 Feb 2021 13:32:13 GMT
server: nginx
:authority: mywebsite.com
:method: GET
:path: /testimage
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control: no-cache
cookie: *************************
pragma: no-cache
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: none
sec-fetch-user: ?1
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.192 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

**PHP:**

**Setting up the test image**

```
// In early attempts, was pulling a PNG file from a 3rd-party source with file_get_contents().
// Now I'm just testing with inline base64 sample data.
// In both cases, the above issue exists.

// Inline base64 PNG data (about 7kb, a cartoon character)
$sampleImage = 'data:image/png;base64,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';

// Process base64 data
$result = base64_decode(str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $sampleImage));
```

**RETURN TRIAL #1**

```
// I don't think I need this, but doing anyways
http_response_code(200);

// Browser displays the image... but browser still reports 404?
return response($result)->header('Content-type','image/png');
```

**RETURN TRIAL #2**

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring($result);
if ($image !== false) {
    header('Content-Type: image/png');

    // Sends response to client
    // Browser displays the image... but browser still reports 404?
    imagepng($image);

    imagedestroy($image);
}
```

Comment: _"however in console (and network) there's a 404 error reported!"_ - What request gets the 404? Is it really the image file or is it some favicon or similar?

Comment: It's most likely that the URL you are requesting is processed differently by the server than your main domain. Please verify the server is doing the same thing on both URLs and not looking for something else instead (check vhosts or nginx server sections) .

Comment: UPDATE: Added the console error details. There is only one request/response: the PNG from the server. For reference, I don't see any favicon activity that could be conflated as part of the error (should there be?). When visiting homepage, favicon loads normally (visible, and no console errors).

Comment: _“How is this possible?”_ - Just because the response code is 404, does not mean the browser is _forbidden_ from displaying any content that might also have been returned. Whatever you requested here, apparently send valid PNG data back, even with a matching Content-Type header. So it gets displayed, and why not? After all, if you receive an HTML error document response together with a 404, that also usually gets displayed by the browser - the “404 page”. So why should this behave any differently?

Comment: If your script itself did not set a 404 status code, but a 200 - then something else must presumably have overwritten the status code afterwards. Like the nginx apparently involved here for example.

Comment: Check your .htaccess file - this can prevent scripts from accessing files even if those files are themselves accessible.